# Setting a drag image in GWT 2.4

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I need to implement drag and drop for cells in a `CellTable`. Following the example from the [MobileWebApp](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.4/samples/mobilewebapp/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/sample/mobilewebapp/client/desktop/DesktopTaskEditView.java) I implemented a custom draggable cell:

```
public class DraggableCell extends AbstractCell<ProductProxy>{

interface Templates extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
    @SafeHtmlTemplates.Template("<div draggable=\"true\">{0}</div>")
    SafeHtml simpleTextTemplate(String text);
}

protected Templates templates = GWT.create(Templates.class);

public DraggableCell() {
    super("dragstart");
}

@Override
public void render(Context context, ProductProxy value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb){
        sb.append(templates.simpleTextTemplate(value.getName()));
}

@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, 
                           ProductProxy value, NativeEvent event, 
                           ValueUpdater<ProductProxy> valueUpdater) {
    final Integer cursorOffsetX = 0;
    final Integer cursorOffsetY = 0;

    if ("dragstart".equals(event.getType())) {
        // Save the ID of the entity
        DataTransfer dataTransfer = event.getDataTransfer();
        dataTransfer.setData("text", value.getId());

        SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
        sb.appendEscaped(value.getSn());

        Element element = DOM.createDiv();
        element.setInnerHTML(sb.toSafeHtml().asString());

        // Set the helper image.
        dataTransfer.setDragImage(element, cursorOffsetX, cursorOffsetY);
    }
}
```

I use a new element for the drag image (in the MobileWebApp they just use the parent element), but unfortunately no image is displayed during the drag. I thought that maybe the new element needs to be attached to the DOM first, so I created a helperPanel and attached the element to it:

```
DOM.getElementById("dragHelperPanel").appendChild(element);
// Set the helper image.
dataTransfer.setDragImage(element, cursorOffsetX, cursorOffsetY);
```

This works fine in Firefox 6, but no luck in Chrome (using the latest stable version), so maybe this isn't the right way to do it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the GWT Drag & Drop API. I have used it and its a good one even in mobile devices.

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/

Try the Demo here,

http://allen-sauer.com/com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.demo.DragDropDemo/DragDropDemo.html

Its quite simple to implement and don't have any issues so far for me

Comment: Well I already have an working solution using the gwtquery dnd plugin (http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/). I was trying to transition to a native GWT approach, in order to reduce my external dependencies. But unfortunately native support for drag&drop is poorly documented.